# Black Screen of Death question on a Dell Inspiron 7348 2-in-1

Tags: boot, grub2, dell

So, I've been searching for a solution to this issue. I've been scouring forums looking for an answer to my black screen of death problem. I have an Dell Inspiron 7348 2-in-1. Currently this is running 17.04, but have tried various flavors. I know this is driver/hardware related, but not sure how I can fix it permanantly . Unfortunately I'm not sure of how to get additional hardware specs from the grub menu, and this is a single boot system. Here ultimately is the problem. I have loaded various forms of linux onto this system and almost like clockwork after a week running fine after install, I'll shut it down and reboot, and I get a black screen. After instal, for that week it shuts down and starts up with no problems. I've tried nomodeset in the grub menu. If I insert a USB stick in and got through the "try Linux" it comes up just fine. Any help would be appreciated, and if more info is needed, I can try to elaborate more. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This really sounds like something you won't be solving by editing a config file. Have you considered contacting the manufacturer?

Comment: I did. Unfortunately, as soon as I said Linux, Dell pretty much blew me off.

Comment: That is indeed a sad state of affairs. I don't know about the exact warrenty conditions, but it sounds like a hardware fault should be covered regardless of the operating system. On the other hand it might be helpfull to identify the problem.
As immediate diagnostic steps, after you experience the crash, boot a live os and have a look at the [system log](https://www.google.de/search?q=system+log+file+linux&oq=system+log+file+linux&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3607j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) of the installed os.

Comment: @MrPaulch If it runs fine in a live session and after installation at least for a while, not an hardware issue.

Comment: @Waldo513 Try here: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3525

Comment: @MichaelBay nevertheless checking the system log of a crashing installation would be helpful. As to whether it is a hardware problem, I can't be certain of course. But it does sound like it. I had a case with a faulty memory controller once. Only symptom: the system would refuse to boot after a couple of days for no apparent reason.